# Can failing javascript on a web page cause all other scripts to fail?

Tags: javascript

I suspect that a 3rd party analytics script on our page is causing our Google Adwords conversion script (later in the page) not to run where the a fore mentioned analytics fails to load external resources.

What is the standard behavior for a web browser in this scenario? Can subsequent scripts fail to run even if in separate  tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have several script tags, each tag can fail on its own without affecting the other tags.

But:

- If some of the executed scripts modify the webpage, this might cause other scripts to fail because of the changes you did
- The creation of global variables with conflicting names might cause trouble, too!

---

EDIT: Tested in Opera:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>=;</script>
    <script>alert("Hello!");</script>
  </head>
</html>
```

This snippet will create an error:

```
Inline script compilation
Syntax error at line 1 while loading: expected expression, got '='
```

But it will still display:

```
Hello!
```

---

EDIT²: So, I uploaded the following test-code:

```
<html>
    <body id="content" bgColor="red">
        <script>?=;</script>
        <script>document.getElementById("content").bgColor = "green";</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And executed it via Browsershots.org, so I can see the result w/o opening the shots ;)

Working:

- Firefox 1.5+ (XP / Ubuntu / Debian / FreeBSD)
- Galeon 2.0.6 (Debian)
- SeaMonkey 1.1.15+ (Debian / Win 2008 / XP)
- Kazehakase 0.5.4 (Debian / FreeBSD)
- Iceape 1.1.13+ (Debian)
- Konqueror 3.5+ (Debian / FreeBSD)
- Opera 9.64+ (FreeBSD)
- Epiphany 2.22 (FreeBSD)
- Icewasel 3.5.16 (Debian)
- Chrome 1.0.154.59+ (Debian / Win 2008)
- MSIE 9.0+ (Win 2008)
- Flock 0.8+ (Win 2000 / 2008 / XP)
- Lunascape 6.7 (Win 2003)
- Camino 2.1.2 (OS X 10)
- Avant 8.02+ (Win 2003 / 2008 / XP)
- iCab 5.0 (OS X 10)
- OmniWeb 622 (OS X 10)
- Safari 3.2.3+ (OS X 10)
- Stainless 0.8 (OS X 10)
- Maxthon 3.4.2 (Win 8)
- Navigator 9 (XP)
- Netscape 8.1.3 (XP)

A **+** means that it was successful on all following versions included in the test, EXCEPT the ones listed below

NOT WORKING

- Dillo 0.8.6; 2.0; 3.0.2 (Debian)
- Lynx 2.8.8 (Gentoo) :D
- MSIE 4.01 (XP)
- MSIE 5.5; 6.0; 7.0; 8.0 (Win 2008) ***
- Chrome 18.0.1025.168 (Ubuntu 12.04 LTE)
- SeaMonkey 2.12 (Ubuntu 12.04 LTE)

*** Execution stopped by Window:

```
Syntax Error
Do you want to continue running scripts on this page?
[ Yes | No ]
```

Comment: Thanks, a test like this shows that it's certainly possible for other scripts not to fail, though I wonder if all browsers behave the same for all conditions that can fail scripts. This I unfortunately don't have time to test.

Answer (score 1):

I've often had issues in some versions of IE where JS errors appear to make the entire engine stop loading any further source (in different files and therefore different tags).  I don't have concrete knowledge but I'd think it can happen depending on the browser and the settings of that browser.  My practical experience is that it certainly happens and that fixing the errors indicated can repair entirely unrelated code.

Comment: Well, lets hope that nowadays all browser are following the new HTML5 standards. There is defined, that no interference shall occur.

Comment: That would be nice.  I won't hold my breath for IE, particularly not older versions that are clinging on.  And in this case I'd say that having code that isn't broken is always a good thing :)

Comment: You're right. But having a browser that doesn't break code is even better! :))

Comment: That's why I never develop for IE but then get instantly depressed when I have to support it.

Comment: But I was very surprised by IE9 which fully supported a HTML5 canvas application including AJAX-Requests and Event-Handlers without the need to do things like attachEvent or Microsoft.XMLHTTP. The only thing I did was adding `<!doctype html>`

Comment: This is exactly our experience